# jq - how to filter values in an inner array without knowing the key

Tags: json, select, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "ids": {
    "sda": [
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi2"
    ],
    "sdb": [
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0"
    ],
    "sdb1": [
      "lvm-pv-uuid-lvld3A-oA4k-hC19-DXzv-D0Fq-xyME-BwgJid",
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0-part1"
    ],
    "sdc": [
      "lvm-pv-uuid-pWes2W-dgYF-l8hG-La48-9ozH-hPdU-MOkOtf",
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi1"
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to search for `.*scsi0$` in the values of the inner array and get `sdb` as the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [JSON jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) [`endswith`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#endswith(str)) to filter results:

```
.ids | to_entries[] | select(.value[] | endswith("scsi0")) | .key
```

Results in:

```
"sdb"
```

Try it here: https://jqplay.org/s/DAhKosXXgiA

---

Let's break it down...

First get `.ids`, which returns:

```
{
  "sda": [
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi2"
  ],
  "sdb": [
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0"
  ],
  "sdb1": [
    "lvm-pv-uuid-lvld3A-oA4k-hC19-DXzv-D0Fq-xyME-BwgJid",
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0-part1"
  ],
  "sdc": [
    "lvm-pv-uuid-pWes2W-dgYF-l8hG-La48-9ozH-hPdU-MOkOtf",
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi1"
  ]
}
```

...then [pipe](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Pipe:%7C) the results to the [to_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#) function to convert that to an array of `{key, value}` objects.

`.ids | to_entries` returns:

```
[
  {
    "key": "sda",
    "value": [
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "sdb",
    "value": [
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "sdb1",
    "value": [
      "lvm-pv-uuid-lvld3A-oA4k-hC19-DXzv-D0Fq-xyME-BwgJid",
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0-part1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "sdc",
    "value": [
      "lvm-pv-uuid-pWes2W-dgYF-l8hG-La48-9ozH-hPdU-MOkOtf",
      "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi1"
    ]
  }
]
```

...next stream the list of objects with the [iterator operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-object-value-iterator) `.[]`.

`.ids | to_entries[]` returns:

```
{
  "key": "sda",
  "value": [
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi2"
  ]
}
{
  "key": "sdb",
  "value": [
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0"
  ]
}
{
  "key": "sdb1",
  "value": [
    "lvm-pv-uuid-lvld3A-oA4k-hC19-DXzv-D0Fq-xyME-BwgJid",
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0-part1"
  ]
}
{
  "key": "sdc",
  "value": [
    "lvm-pv-uuid-pWes2W-dgYF-l8hG-La48-9ozH-hPdU-MOkOtf",
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi1"
  ]
}
```

...and [select](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) from a stream of values, `.ids | to_entries[] | select(.value[])` where value endswith "scsi0",  `select(.value[] | endswith("scsi0"))` :

```
{
  "key": "sdb",
  "value": [
    "scsi-0QEMU_QEMU_HARDDISK_drive-scsi0"
  ]
}
```

...finally, get the key value.

`.ids | to_entries[] | select(.value[] | endswith("scsi0")) | .key` returns:

```
"sdb"
```

Command line:

```
jq '.ids | to_entries[] | select(.value[] | endswith("scsi0")) | .key'
```

Try it here: https://jqplay.org/s/DAhKosXXgiA

Answer (score 0):

```
.ids | to_entries[] | select(.value[] | test(".*scsi0$")) | .key
```

Will print the key if *any* value in the array matches your regex.

If none match, there will be no output.

---

`to_entries` is uses to easy capture the key of the objects.

`select` to filter the values

`.value[] | test(".*scsi0$")` checks each value to the regex

`.key` and we show the key of the result

---

##### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/osxCWB3mUlA)

Comment: Also works, but I accepted the answer above, because it is more detailed. But thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Sure m8, not sure why tho, a few links to the docs with the same answer, fine..